# Grid design went wrong

Tags: html, css

So, my page is not what I wanted, although I followed instruction (which most of the time are not clear). I tried to find what went work but nothing...., I verified my code with the validator again nothing, everything looks ok. I even tried different browsers. Can some help me?

Also, I had to do this: Go to the Grid Spacing Styles section. Create a style rule to apply the Border Box model to the div elements belonging to the following classes: container, row, classes that begin with the column, cell, and elements nested within div elements belonging to the cell class. But unfortunately, I'm lost, any help here as well would be awesome!

[This is how the page should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEruv.png) I know that the image is kinda small but I couldn't upload a picture bigger than 2MB

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <!--
       New Perspectives on HTML5 and CSS3, 7th Edition
       Tutorial 3
       Case Problem 2

       Costume Expressions Front Page
       Author: Martin Evtimov
       Date: 02-08-2018  

       Filename: ce_front.html
       -->
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>Costume Expressions</title>
       <link href="ce_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link href="ce_grids.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
       <header>
          <nav>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Enter Site</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Track Orders</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Info</a></li>
             </ul>
          </nav>
       </header>
       <div id="container">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="column80">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="column100 cell" id="logo">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_logo.png" alt="Costume Expressions" /></a>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="column50 cell">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_image04.png" alt="Birthday Party Costumes" /></a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column25 cell">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_image05.png" alt="Makeup Sales"/></a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column25 cell">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_image06.png" alt="Costume Specials"/></a>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="column20">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="column100 cell">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_image01.png" alt="Find us on Facebook" /></a>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="column100 cell">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_image02.png" alt="Follow us on Twitter" /></a>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="column100 cell">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_image03.png" alt="Masks on Sale" /></a>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="column100 cell">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_image07.png" alt="Wig Specials" /></a>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
             <div class="column20">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="column100 cell">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_image08.png" alt="Theater Costumes" /></a>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="column100 cell">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_image12.png" alt="Props for Sale" /></a>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="column80">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="column50 cell">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_image09.png" alt="Sales on Super Hero Costumes" /></a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column25 cell">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_image10.png" alt="Candy Sale" /></a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column25 cell">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_image11.png" alt="Hats for Sale" /></a>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="column25 cell">
                      <a href="#"><img src="ce_image13.png" alt="Christmas Specials" /></a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column75">
                      <div class="row">
                         <div class="column67 cell">
                            <a href="#"><img src="ce_image14.png" alt="Classic Costumes" /></a>
                         </div>
                         <div class="column33 cell">
                            <a href="#"><img src="ce_image15.png" alt="Shipping Fees" /></a>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                         <div class="column33 cell">
                            <a href="#"><img src="ce_image16.png" alt="Halloween Costumes" /></a>
                         </div>
                         <div class="column33 cell">
                            <a href="#"><img src="ce_image17.png" alt="Halloween Costumes" /></a>
                         </div>
                         <div class="column33 cell">
                            <a href="#"><img src="ce_image18.png" alt="Halloween Costumes" /></a>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
             <div class="column20 cell">
                <a href="#"><img src="ce_image19.png" alt="Masks for Sale" /></a>
             </div>
             <div class="column40 cell">
                <a href="#"><img src="ce_image20.png" alt="Mardis Gras Specials" /></a>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <footer>
          Costume Expressions<br />
          3411 Torrence Dr.<br />
          Rockville, MD 20850
       </footer>
    </body>
    </html>





    @charset "utf-8";
    /*
       New Perspectives on HTML5 and CSS3, 7th Edition
       Tutorial 3
       Case Problem 2

       Style Sheet for Grids used in the Costume Expressions Front Page
       Author: Martin Evtimov
       Date: 02-08-2018  

       Filename: ce_grids.css

    */


    /* Grid Rows Styles */
    div.row {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      clear: both;
    }
    div.row {
      float: left;
    }


    /* Grid Columns Styles */
    div.column100 {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
    }
    div.column50 {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;  
    }
    div.column33 {
      width: 33.33%;
      float: left;
    }
    div.column67 {
      width: 66.67%;
      float: left;
    }
    div.column25 {
      width: 25%;
      float: left;
    }
    div.column75 {
      width: 75%;
      float: left;
    }
    div.column20 {
      width: 20%;
      float: left;
    }
    div.column40 {
      width: 40%;
      float: left;
    }
    div.column60 {
      width: 60%;
      float: left;
    }
    div.column80 {
      width: 80%;
      float: left;
    }
    /* Grid Spacing Styles */




@charset "utf-8";
/*
   New Perspectives on HTML5 and CSS3, 7th Edition
   Tutorial 3
   Case Problem 2

   Style Sheet for Costume Expressions Front Page
   Author: Martin Evtimov
   Date: 02-08-2018  

   Filename: ce_styles.css
*/


/* Window and Body Styles */
html {
  background-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
}
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 95%;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 960px;
}
body img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Body Header Styles */
body>header {
  background-color: rgb(191, 168, 170);
  height: 40px;
}
body>header>nav un li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
body>header>nav>ul>li {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}
nav a:link, nav a:visited {
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}
nav a:hover, nav a:active {
 color: rgb(255, 211, 211);
}
/* DIV Container Styles */
div#container {
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
div[class^="cell"]>a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

/* Footer Styles */
footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  bottom: 8px;
  color: rgb(143, 33, 36);
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

Comment: You should post your code at Plunker (https://plnkr.co/) so we can see the differences between what u have done and what u expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you insert it the border box model to the hw above. (I went through the exact same step)

```
.container, .row, div.column, div.cell, div.a {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```